# If $\mathcal{N}=\{(-b,\infty),(a,\infty): a,b\in\mathbb{R}\}$, then ${\mathcal{A}}_{\sigma}(\mathcal{N})=\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $$\mathcal{N}=\{(-b,\infty),(a,\infty): a,b\in\mathbb{R}\}$$ I want to show that the $\sigma$-algebra generated by a family of $\mathcal{N}$, is the family of Borel sets,  $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$.

Attempt:

1. I know that for $\mathcal{M},\mathcal{K}\in \mathcal{P}(X)$, if $\mathcal{M}\subseteq\mathcal{K}\subseteq {\mathcal{A}}_{\sigma}(\mathcal{M})$, then ${\mathcal{A}}_{\sigma}(\mathcal{M})={\mathcal{A}}_{\sigma}(\mathcal{K})$.
2. I also know that for  $I_o=\{(a,b): a\leq b, \ \  \ a,b \in\mathbb{R}\}$, and $\mathcal{O}$, the family of open sets in $\mathbb{R}$, $${\mathcal{A}}_{\sigma}(I_o)={\mathcal{A}}_{\sigma}(\mathcal{O})$$
3. And that $\mathcal{N}\subseteq \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$
4. And since $(a,b)=(-\infty,b)\cap(a,\infty)$, we have that $I_o\subseteq {\mathcal{A}}_{\sigma}(\mathcal{N})$.

How to continue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the theorem:

Let $\mathcal{M}\subseteq \mathcal{P}(X)$  and let $\mathcal{A}$ be a $\sigma$-algebra containing $\mathcal{M}$. Then ${\mathcal{A}} = {\mathcal{A}}_{\sigma}(\mathcal{M})$ **iff** $\mathcal{A}$ contained in every $\sigma$-algebra  containing $\mathcal{M}$.

From 4. we have that ${\mathcal{A}}_{\sigma}(I_o)\subseteq {\mathcal{A}}_{\sigma}(\mathcal{N})$, and from 3. we have that ${\mathcal{A}}_{\sigma}(\mathcal{N})\subseteq \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$. But ${\mathcal{A}}_{\sigma}(I_o)=\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$. Thus $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})={\mathcal{A}}_{\sigma}(\mathcal{N})$.